# jquery javascript click function from within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an external JS file that contains the following jQuery code:

```
var globalNames = { next: 'input[name="next"]'};
var globalElements = { next: $e.find(globalNames.next) };

initQuiz: function() {
  globalElements.next.click(function () {

        if (y.forcingQuestionSolve && !j[c.index()] && (y.quizSummeryHide || !y.reviewQustion)) {
            alert(WpProQuizGlobal.questionNotSolved);
            return false
                }
        i.methode.nextQuestion()
     }
);
```

the `globalElements.next.click` function is triggered by a click on a button:

```
<input type="button" name="next" value="Next" class="Button" ">
```

What I would like to do is call this `p.next.click` function from a Input Checkbox click.
I have added the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "input[class='questionInput']", function () {
    alert("Thanks for checking me");
    // This is the line I'm not sure off !?!?
    $('next').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

As you can see, I have tried to call the trigger event but its not working.

I have to note that the 2 jQuery statements are not combined in document, they are separate.

EDIT: Added Correct Variables  (global*)

Comment: `$('next')` is selecting `<next>`, not `<input name="next">` You're already using the correct selector though?

Comment: `$("[name='next']").trigger('click');`

Comment: `$('next')` will try to find an HTML element that is `name`. More preciselt, it'd be searching for tags called `<name>`. The `globalNames` might be global or not, depending on how your file is formatted. If it is indeed global, then you can do `$(globalNames.next)`, if it isn't, it should be `$('input[name="next"]')`

Comment: If `p.next` is an HTMLElement, use `$(p.next).trigger('click')` If not, what exactly is `p.next`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you only forgot to dedicate the button which has to be triggered.

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "input[class='questionInput']", function () {
  alert("Thanks for checking me");
  // This is the line I'm not sure off !?!?
  $('[name=next]').trigger('click');
  // $('.Button').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone.. I used the following code from Calvin Nunes-

```
$("[name='next']").trigger('click');
```

Craig.